# ListView sorted, using comparator

Tags: android, listview, comparator

This is in onCreate method:

```
list = dba.getAllFriends();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Friend>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
adapter.sort(Friend.NAME_COMPARATOR);
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And this is the comparator:

```
public static final Comparator<Friend> NAME_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Friend>() {

    public int compare(final Friend friend1, final Friend friend2) {
        return friend1.getName().compareTo(friend2.getName());
    }
};
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

EDIT:

```
list = dba.getAllFriends();
    Collections.sort(list, Friend.NAME_COMPARATOR);
    Log.d("ListSorted", list.toString());
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Friend>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I also tried it like this and I got sorted output (LogCat) but in ListView it stays unsorted. Wtf?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Collections.sort(List list,Comparator c);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29)

In your case :

```
Collections.sort(yourFriendsList,Friend.NAME_COMPARATOR);
```

Or more preferably use the [`sort`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) method available in your adapter to get it done.

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);   //or whatever your sorting algorithm
    }
});
```

Goog luck!

Comment: How does the second option differs from mine? The only difference is that I have it in another class accessing it by static variable. Or am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @Ondrej'zatokar'Tokár can i looking for Friend class?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my onResume method I did not update it with the sorting. True is I don't know why on start of my app it's onResume method called so if you leave a comment I will be glad.
BTW both ways are working if I sort list or I sort it with:

```
adapter.sort(Friend.NAME_COMPARATOR);
```

Or:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ListView lv = this.getListView();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list = dba.getAllFriends();
    Collections.sort(list, Friend.NAME_COMPARATOR);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Friend>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.invalidate();
}
```